# Arrow Head at every point on graph

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I am trying to observe the flow of the vector. So I want to use arrow heads to show the flow at every point. I see a lot of examples on how to get one large arrow head but not at every point. I am trying to plot the "vector" variable with arrow heads.

```
f[x_, y_] = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
gradientf[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}];
pnts1 = {{-1.8, 0.2}, {-1.8, 0.4}, {-1.8, 0.6}, {-1.8, 0.8}, {-1.8, 
1.}, {-1.8, 1.2}, {-1.8, 1.4}, {-1.8, 1.6}, {-1.8, 1.8}, {-1.8, 
2.}, {-1.6, 0.2}, {-1.6, 0.4}, {-1.6, 0.6}, {-1.6, 0.8}, {-1.6, 
1.}, {-1.6, 1.2}, {-1.6, 1.4}, {-1.6, 1.6}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-1.6, 
2.}, {-1.4, 0.2}, {-1.4, 0.4}, {-1.4, 0.6}, {-1.4, 0.8}, {-1.4, 
1.}, {-1.4, 1.2}, {-1.4, 1.4}, {-1.4, 1.6}, {-1.4, 1.8}, {-1.4, 
2.}, {-1.2, 0.2}, {-1.2, 0.4}, {-1.2, 0.6}, {-1.2, 0.8}, {-1.2, 
1.}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.4}, {-1.2, 1.6}, {-1.2, 1.8}, {-1.2, 
2.}, {-1., 0.2}, {-1., 0.4}, {-1., 0.6}, {-1., 0.8}, {-1., 
1.}, {-1., 1.2}, {-1., 1.4}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1., 1.8}, {-1., 
2.}, {-0.8, 0.6}, {-0.8, 0.8}, {-0.8, 1.}, {-0.8, 1.2}, {-0.8, 
1.4}, {-0.8, 1.6}, {-0.8, 1.8}, {-0.8, 2.}, {-0.6, 0.8}, {-0.6, 
1.}, {-0.6, 1.2}, {-0.6, 1.4}, {-0.6, 1.6}, {-0.6, 1.8}, {-0.6, 
2.}, {-0.4, 1.}, {-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 1.4}, {-0.4, 1.6}, {-0.4, 
1.8}, {-0.4, 2.}, {-0.2, 1.}, {-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {-0.2, 
1.6}, {-0.2, 1.8}, {-0.2, 2.}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.2}, {0., 
1.4}, {0., 1.6}, {0., 1.8}, {0., 2.}, {0.2, 1.}, {0.2, 1.2}, {0.2,
 1.4}, {0.2, 1.6}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.2, 2.}, {0.4, 1.}, {0.4, 
1.2}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.4, 1.6}, {0.4, 1.8}, {0.4, 2.}, {0.6, 
0.8}, {0.6, 1.}, {0.6, 1.2}, {0.6, 1.4}, {0.6, 1.6}, {0.6, 
1.8}, {0.6, 2.}, {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.8, 1.}, {0.8, 
1.2}, {0.8, 1.4}, {0.8, 1.6}, {0.8, 1.8}, {0.8, 2.}, {1., 
0.2}, {1., 0.4}, {1., 0.6}, {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.}, {1., 1.2}, {1., 
1.4}, {1., 1.6}, {1., 1.8}, {1., 2.}, {1.2, 0.2}, {1.2, 
0.4}, {1.2, 0.6}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.}, {1.2, 1.2}, {1.2, 
1.4}, {1.2, 1.6}, {1.2, 1.8}, {1.2, 2.}, {1.4, 0.2}, {1.4, 
0.4}, {1.4, 0.6}, {1.4, 0.8}, {1.4, 1.}, {1.4, 1.2}, {1.4, 
1.4}, {1.4, 1.6}, {1.4, 1.8}, {1.4, 2.}, {1.6, 0.2}, {1.6, 
0.4}, {1.6, 0.6}, {1.6, 0.8}, {1.6, 1.}, {1.6, 1.2}, {1.6, 
1.4}, {1.6, 1.6}, {1.6, 1.8}, {1.6, 2.}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.8, 
0.4}, {1.8, 0.6}, {1.8, 0.8}, {1.8, 1.}, {1.8, 1.2}, {1.8, 
1.4}, {1.8, 1.6}, {1.8, 1.8}, {1.8, 2.}, {2., 0.2}, {2., 
0.4}, {2., 0.6}, {2., 0.8}, {2., 1.}, {2., 1.2}, {2., 1.4}, {2., 
1.6}, {2., 1.8}, {2., 2.}};
vector = pnts1 + gradientf @@@ pnts1;
ListPlot[vector]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** You can also use `ListLinePlot` after pairing the elements of `pnts1` and `vector` and post-process the output to change `Line`s to `Arrow`s:

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{pnts1, vector}], 
  PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium], AspectRatio -> 1] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use `pnts1` as the option value for the option `VectorPoints` in `VectorPlot`:

```
VectorPlot[gradientf[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 VectorPoints -> pnts1, VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}, 
 VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"], 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point@pnts1}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is taking in the function just gradientf[x,y] when I need it to be taking in pnts1+gradient f[x,y] for the plot. Where pnts1 is the option value.

Comment: @subrinarafiq, please check the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `VectorPlot`:

```
f[x_, y_] = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
gradientf[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]

VectorPlot[gradientf[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, VectorPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

or with constant size of arrows:

```
VectorPlot[gradientf[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, VectorPoints -> 20,
  VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

See help on `VectorPlot` for more variants of presentations.

Comment: that just graphs the "gradientf" not what was defined as the vector aka pnts1+gradientf@@@pnts1, which provides a whole new list of points.

Comment: Arrow means direction, it requires two points, see help on `Arrow`. What do you mean by "plot vector variable with arrow heads"?

Comment: Try if this is what you want: `Graphics[{Blue, Arrowheads[0.03], Arrow /@ Transpose[{pnts1, vector}]}, Frame -> True]`.

Comment: Yes, I have a list of points so one arrow would be for example from (-1.8,.2) to (-1.6,.2) then another from (-1.6,2) to (-1.4,.2) if that makes sense. And the process would repeat for the rest of the points.

Comment: Do you want to connect each point from `pnts1` with the corresponding point from `vector`? If so, use command from my previous comment `Graphics[...]`.

Comment: Or do you want to connect consecutive pairs of points of `vector`?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to use points from the vector not pnts 1. I want to connect to consecutive pairs of points of vector!

Comment: Try this `Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.03], Arrow /@ Partition[vector, 2, 1]},Frame -> True]`. It makes consecutive pairs of points and then connects each pair of points with arrow. But for me the picture is not of much sense.

Comment: The arrows are connecting upwards, from the lowest point of a y value to the highest for a specific x. But they should be going from left to right until it hits the last , aka highest, x-value for a specific y value, in which it should start connecting arrows again at the next y value if that makes sense.

Comment: y-values of `vector` are all different, so for a particular `y` there will be only one point. Well, you can `Split` y-values into some ranges and connect points in each such band, but I don't understand the idea behind this, sorry.

Comment: Smth. like: `bands = Partition[Subdivide[Sequence @@ MinMax[vector[[All, 2]]], 10], 2, 1]; t = Table[Select[vector, Between[#[[2]], i] &], {i, bands}]; p = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ (SortBy[#, First] & /@ t); Graphics@Map[Arrow, p, {2}]`, change first 10 to needed number of vertical ranges.